# Kubernetes adding insecure-registries

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, yaml

I have my docker-compose deployment that needs to pull the image from an insecure registry, so I will have to add to update the file /etc/docker/daemon.json and add the following entry to make it work.

```
{
  "insecure-registries": [hostname] 
}
```

Now i want to move this deployment from standalone docker to Kubernetes, How can i update my Kubernetes namespace to use deploy the image from an insecure registry?

Comment: Did Harsh Manvar solution helped you to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for **Docker** you might need to go to each worker node and **edit** the **Docker daemon**, `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "insecure-registries": [hostname] 
}
```

You can use the **K8s Daemon set** the restart of the Docker service on each or Node automated way and if scaling up or down occurs **Daemon set** will perform the changes on new node.

Comment: Is there any better way to achieve the same at the namespace level instead of going to every node and updating it?